# Number of spanning trees of a special graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, trees

In a certain exercise I am given a graph consisting of three triangles united by one central vertex, having a total of 8 vertex and 9 edges. I am asked to find the number of spanning trees. It seems really easy and I find it weird to be something so simple, that's why I prefer asking here in order to assure the exactitude of my answer. Here is my attempt:

In order to form a tree, all edges than can create a cycle have to dissapear, but since I am looking for spanning trees, all vertex have to be connected. Therefore, for each triangle, one just can remove one edge, having three options for each triangle. Therefore, there are $3^3 = 27$ options. Is this as simple as that?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  "*Is this as simple as that?*"  Early examples can often be simple because they are trying to reinforce definitions and problem types.  The challenge here was not in being clever or performing difficult calculations, but rather in understanding what a spanning tree is in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have already seen that the exercise asks me for $n$ triangles, which means that there would be $2n+1$ vertex and $3n$ edges. I imagine that the answer would be $3^n$, right?

Comment: Assuming the vertices are all labeled, yes that is exactly right.

Comment: And if it weren't labeled, there would be a single one, correct?

Comment: Mm... in the case of unlabeled graphs, I would need to think harder on it, but it is certainly more than one.  I *expect* that we can still figure out which the "original root" was, since all leafs will either be next to the root or next to a degree-2 node.  The original root will be the only node of degree higher than two (*except I suppose in one case where we had two triangles and the spanning tree in question is $P_5$*).  We would have every triangle is broken up into effectively two possible and order irrelevant, so we count with stars and bars as $\binom{n+2-1}{2-1}=n+1$ possible.

Comment: For instance, in the case of two triangles, the star graph $K_{1,4}$ (*or $S_4$ or however you like to notate it*) is certainly a "*different*" spanning tree than the path graph $P_5$.  The case of one triangle is special, we can not remember which node was the original root there, there is effectively only one unlabeled tree on three vertices.